# UITapGestureRecognizer recognized as UILongPressGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, gesture

I have an issue with the UITapGestureRecognizer in my collection view and I don't know the error.

I want to do a custom action when there is a long press gesture, and when there is a tap gesture I want to do nothing, so I have these methods:

```
- (void)activateSelectionMode:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gr
{
    if (![self.collectionView allowsSelection]) {
        [self.collectionView setAllowsSelection:YES];
        NSLog(@"Seleccion activada");
    }
}

- (void)pruebaTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tr
{
    NSLog(@"tap");
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch
{
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.collectionView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:touchPoint];
    if (indexPath != nil && [gestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]])
    {
        CVCell *cell =  (CVCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        if ([[cell checkImage] isHidden]) {
            // TODO: Añadir la celda a la lista de celdas seleccionadas
            [[cell checkImage] setHidden:NO];
            NSLog(@"Seleccionada celda %@", [[cell titleLabel] text]);
        } else {
            // TODO: Quitar la celda de la lista de celdas seleccionadas
            [[cell checkImage] setHidden:YES];
            NSLog(@"No seleccionada celda %@", [[cell titleLabel] text]);
        }

        NSLog(@"Entra");

        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

IF I comment the last method, each method is recognized perfectly, but if I don't comment the last method, the tap gesture is recognized as long press gesture. Here I assign the gesture to the collection view:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(pruebaTap:)];
tap.delegate = self;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:tap];

UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPress = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(activateSelectionMode:)];
longPress.delegate = self;
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:longPress];
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: "IF I comment the last method, each method is recognized perfectly, but if I don't comment the last method"- 
--what do u mean by last method?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure weather you have implemented the below gesture delegate method or not.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer 
shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer
:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;
```

If you have not implemented then no problem because default implementation returns NO but if you have implemented & returned YES then both the gesture will be recognized. May be returning NO will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

It will definitely recognize  long press gesture because , you have added it last, what you are doing is , you are adding 2 gestures on same view, so here your longPress gesture will overlap on UITapGestureRecognizer gesture(that is tap), so everytime longpress gesture will be called.

what you can do is , you will have to add one at a time.

Comment: I had the same problem without add the tap recognizer :/

Comment: what exactly you want to say? you have not added tap gesture, and you have only added  UILongpress gesture and longpress method(activateSelectionMode) is not calling???